# Variance of $Y=\sin(U)$ where $U$ is uniformly distributed

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $U$ is distributed according to the uniform distribution on $[0, \pi/2]$, and $Y=\sin(U)$, find $V(Y)$. Is the arcsine distribution appropriate, or is there any simpler way of determining the variance?

Comment: What mean $R(0,\pi/2)$ ?

Comment: Hint: given a random variable $X$ with pdf $f$, and a measurable function $g$, $E(g(X))=\int g(x)f(x)dx$.

Comment: @Surb The $R()$ was referring to the rectangular distribution in this case.

Comment: $V(Y)=E(Y^2)-(E(Y))^2$. So find the two expectations from definition.